# Give a std::vector ownership of another vector's memory?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

I have a constructor that looks like this:

```
Thing::Thing(std::vector<uint8> & data){
    m_data = data; // m_data is also a vector<uint8>
    // do other stuff
}
```

However, `data` holds a pretty large chunk of memory, and instead of copying it, I'd like `data` to simply give it up to `m_data`, as the caller will never need it after constructing this object.  What's the best way to do this in C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the move assignment operator.

```
m_data = std::move(data);
```

It will be better to change the argument type to a value or an rvalue reference so that the user of the function is not surprised that the contents of the input argument have been moved.

```
Thing::Thing(std::vector<uint8>&& data){
    m_data = std::move(data);
    // do other stuff
}
```

Given that, the calling function will be aware that they need to pass an rvalue reference and won't be surprised by the *move* of the contents.

It will be better to initialize `m_data` using `data` instead of assigning to it.

```
Thing::Thing(std::vector<uint8>&& data) : m_data(std::move(data))
{
    // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Please suggest they pass by value or rvalue reference.  Otherwise it's not clear ownership is being transferred.  Also, as a constructor you should use the class member initialization list.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `m_data = data;` will make a copy since `data` is an lvalue.

Comment: @NathanOliver, even if the argument is of type `td::vector<uint8>&&`?

Comment: Yep.  Anything with a name is a lvalue.  You need `Thing::Thing(std::vector<uint8>&& data){
    m_data = std::move(data);
    // do other stuff
}` or `Thing::Thing(std::vector<uint8>&& data) : m_data(std::move(data)) { //do stuff }`

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks. I am yet to master move semantics.

Comment: I gave it a try, and apparently yes, you do need `std::move()` in both the constructor and the constructor argument, if I did it correctly  https://onlinegdb.com/rkGSecwzr